# Switching SQL queries from association into instance methods

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, self-join

My current User.rb model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children,
           -> (user) { unscope(:where).where("father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id", id: user.id) },
           class_name: "User"

  has_many :grandchildren,
           -> (user) { unscope(:where).where("father_id IN (:ids) OR mother_id IN (:ids)", ids: user.children.ids) },
           class_name: "User"

  belongs_to :mother, class_name: "User", optional: true
  belongs_to :father, class_name: "User", optional: true
end
```

My current data (empty ones are nil):
[image]

All the queries work now:
[image]

But for the `.grandchildren` query, you can see that in the console, three(two repeated queries) queries are created. Is there a way to generate only one query?

I was trying out instance methods since I could put in raw SQL, but couldn't seem to get my head around it. An Example:

```rb
  def children
    sql = ("SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE (father_id = id OR mother_id = id)")
    p ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
```

End goal:

- One query generated when doing `.grandchildren`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this

```rb
  has_many :children,
  -> (user) { unscope(:where).where("father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id", id: user.id) },
   class_name: "User"

  belongs_to :mother, class_name: "User", optional: true
  belongs_to :father, class_name: "User", optional: true

  def grandchildren
    user_id = self.id
    User.where(
      "father_id IN (:ids) OR mother_id IN (:ids)",
      ids: User.where("father_id = :id OR mother_id = :id", id: user_id).pluck(:id)
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
-> (user) { unscope(:where).where("father_id IN (:ids) OR mother_id IN (:ids)", ids: user.children.ids) },
```

With

```
-> (user) do
  scope = unscope(:where)
  children_ids = user.children.select(:id)

  scope
    .where(father_id: children_ids)
    .or(scope.where(mother_id: children_ids))
end
```

Comment: @engineersmnky using `user.children.select(:id)` already creates subquery without loading the records :)

Comment: This was the error `NameError (undefined local variable or method `childrens_id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fca342d1350>)`

Comment: After the edit by @engineersmnky, the error was `NameError (uninitialized constant User::Grandchild)`

Comment: @LeeRenJie no portion of the code provided in this answer would cause that error. I think the problem is you are trying to use `has_many` which will infer a class name from the relationship. In this case though both `children` and `grandchildren` would benefit from being converted to `scopes` rather than relationships. AR Relationships should be joinable and neither one of these can be naturally joinable in the ORM due to the complex nature of the join and your use of an instance `-> (user)` both of which are currently unsupported by the high level DSL provided by AR